# formatear salida printf

Tags: bash

Tengo la siguiente variable que me genera un formato determinado:

```
MSG_AUX=$(cat ${FILE_AUX})
MSG=`printf '%s\n' '---' "${DATE} - ${HOSTNAME}" '---' "$MSG_AUX"`
```

El resultado es:

```
---
01/05/2019
---
dato 1

dato 2

dato 3
```

El fichero **FILE_AUX** que le asigno a la variable **MSG_AUX** contiene los siguiente (sin saltos de linea):

```
dato 1    
dato 2    
dato 3
```

Necesitaría que no me realizara salta de lineas con el printf; es decir, que me quedara sin saltos de linea:

```
---
01/05/2019
---
dato 1    
dato 2    
dato 3
```

Como lo debo de adaptar?

Comment: Que función está leyendo el archivo, yo ejecuto el siguiente código en un archivo imprimir.sh y me muestra la salida deseada, este es el código que tengo dentro de imprimir.sh:
`MSG_AUX=\`cat file.txt\`
printf '%s\n' '---' "${DATE} - ${HOSTNAME}" '---' "$MSG_AUX"`

Answer (score 1):

finalmente lo he solucionado poniendo al final del cat:

```
tr -d "\n\r"
```

gracias igualmente!

Comment: Eso es porque el problema está con los saltos de linea de tu archivo. Mejor arregla tu archivo en lugar de aplicar parches, a menos que así te venga necesariamente la información extraída.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usando.

```
$ MSG=$(
    printf '%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n' \
    '----' \
    "$(date +'%d/%m/%y') - ${HOSTNAME}" \
    '----' \
    "$(cat file)"
)
$ echo "$MSG"
```

Es exactamente lo mismo, el único cambio es que, para mayor claridad, creé 4 placeholders `%s` para las 4 cadenas,

1. `"---"`
2. `"$(date +'%d/%m/%y') - ${HOSTNAME}"`
3. `"---"`
4. `"$(cat file)"`

Quizás el problema está en el contenido de tu archivo, porque el comando tal como lo pusiste produce el resultado que deseas.